# Eclipse - Ant Build - Package does not exist - javac , but .jar libs are included in build.xml

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, ant

I have searched a lot , as I know there is a good amount of questions in SO related to this subject , though i couldn't find an answer that resolves my issue.

I am using Ant in Eclipse , I want to compile successfully and build a project they hand me out at work .

I have included several **target** elements in my **build.xml** file , one of them called **init** which includes all the .jar files of my lib directory , which resides in the **root** directory of the project.

Following is my **build.xml** file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<project name="xxxName" default="build">
    <property name="build.dir" value="build"/>
    <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="ECLIPSE_HOME" value="../../../eclipse/jee-2022-09/eclipse/"/>
    <property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
    <property name="target" value="1.8"/>
    <property name="source" value="1.8"/>
    <target name="build"  depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build"/>
        <copy todir="build">
            <fileset dir=".">
                <include name="**/*.class"/>
                <include name="**/*.java"/>
                <include name="**/*.xsd"/>
                <include name="**/*.xml"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <mkdir dir="dist"/>
        <jar destfile="dist/Name.aar">
            <fileset dir="build"/>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Service-Class" value="MyService.java"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
    <target name="compile"   depends="init">
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="test" />
    </target>
    <target name="copy-classes">
    <copy todir="${build.dir}/WEB-INF/classes">
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
    <target name="init" >
        <path id="classpath">
            <fileset dir="lib">
                <include name="*.jar" />
            </fileset>
            <pathelement path="${basedir}/lib" />
            </path>
      </target>
</project>
```

My project structure is as follows :

```
MyProject
<!-- Src,lib and build.xml all reside on the same level !-->
  -- src
  -- lib
  -- build.xml
```

My problem :

When trying to invoke the **build** target of my **build.xml** file the javac comes with the following errors :

```
    [javac] C:\Path\File.java:199: error: package org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils does not exist
    [javac]                 xmlWriter.writeCharacters(org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.convertToString(
    [javac]                                                                             ^
    [javac] C:\Path\File.java:199::203: error: package org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils does not exist
    [javac]             xmlWriter.writeCharacters(org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.convertToString(
    [javac]                                                                         ^
    [javac]C:\Path\File.java:199::236: error: package org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils does not exist
    [javac]                                      .append(org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.convertToString(
    [javac]                                                                                ^
    [javac] C:\Path\File.java:199::239: error: package org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils does not exist
    [javac]                         stringToWrite.append(org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.convertToString(
    [javac]                                                                                ^
    [javac] C:\Path\File.java:199::243: error: package org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils does not exist
    [javac]                     stringToWrite.append(org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.convertToString(
    [javac]                                                                            ^
    [javac]C:\Path\File.java:199::272: error: package org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils does not exist
    [javac]                 prefix = org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.getUniquePrefix();
    [javac]                                                            ^
    [javac] C:\Path\File.java:199
    [javac] C:\Path\File.java:199:error: package org.apache.axis2.databinding does not exist
    [javac]                             throw new org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException(
    [javac]                                                                   ^
    [javac] 100 errors
    [javac] only showing the first 100 errors, of 194 total; use -Xmaxerrs if you would like to see more
```

Notice how the compiler states it's only showing first 100 errors from 194, so it actually can't find **ANY** library that is related to the project .

First thing i have tried to do , is check if actually the missing packages exist in the **lib** folder as **.jar** files , and they do . I haven't checked one by one , but at least the first 3 packages for which the javac is complaining about , have their respective **.jar** files in the **lib** folder.

Moreover i know this for a fact as i have anyway added them in the Java build Path of the project and Eclipse could find them and resolve any issues.

My question is what am I missing in the **build** file and causes this issue ?

Any help would be appreciated . thanks

Comment: I don't see any use of the `classpath` path you set up. Shouldn't the `javac` have a `classpathref` to it?

Comment: @greg-449 can you elaborate further , give a snip code or post an answer  ? i won't downvote even if it's wrong.